# Firebase remove children that are no longer part of query

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I used to call `observe` with `.value` which would load all of the children in a query. In real time, when a child would no longer be part of the query (i.e. its timestamp is too old), the `.value` event would get fired and the child's data would be removed from my app. For performance purposes, instead of calling `observe` with `.value`, I separately observe `.childAdded`, `.childChanged`, and `.childRemoved` events. However, none of these events get fired when a child is no longer a part of a query, and the child's data remains in my app. I have tried observing `.childMoved` but that didn't get fired either. How can I replicate this aspect of observing `.value`? Here is some code that represents mine:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var children_query: DatabaseQuery!
    var current_time: TimeInterval {
        return Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.children_query = Database.database().reference().child("children").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryStarting(atValue: current_time)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // refresh query every time this view appears (this is the root view controller so it comes and goes)
        self.children_query = Database.database().reference().child("children").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryStarting(atValue: current_time)

        self.children_query.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value)
        })

        self.children_query.observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value)
        })

        self.children_query.observe(.childRemoved, with: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value)
        })

        self.children_query.observe(.childMoved, with: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value)
        })
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        self.children_query.removeAllObservers()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you easy solution in this situation. Just add direct parent to all values.

```
rootNode: [
    { your first value }
    { your second value }
....
    /* you can add value  here */
    {your last value  }
           ]
```

Now, instead of observe each value, you observe their direct parent. In that way, from the definition of `dataSnapshot` whatever inside changes, it fires `onMessageReceived()` function.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow

Comment: @ArchieGertsman, for the exact proof please look this video on this page. He talks about DataSnapshot. https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: @ArchieGertsman, anything gets changed inside that rootNode, and in observe on rootNode, then based on the definition of DataSnapshot, onMessageReceived() callback will be triggered in your side. I am 100% sure on this.